# C# Linq/Lambda expression: How to select an integer out of a string?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-objects

I think the best way to explain my question is with a short (generic) linq-to-objects code sample:

```
IEnumerable<string> ReadLines(string filename)
{
    string line;
    using (var rdr = new StreamReader(filename))
        while ( (line = rdr.ReadLine()) != null)
           yield return line;
}

IEnumerable<int> XValuesFromFile(string filename)
{
    return ReadLines(filename)
               .Select(l => l.Substring(3,3))
               .Where(l => int.TryParse(l))
               .Select(i => int.Parse(i));
}
```

Notice that this code parses the integer twice.  I know I'm missing an obvious simple way to eliminate one of those calls safely (namely because I've done it before).  I just can't find it right now.  How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I'll go with something like this:

```
IEnumerable<O> Reduce<I,O>(this IEnumerable<I> source, Func<I,Tuple<bool, O>> transform )
{
    foreach (var item in source)
    {
       try
       {
          Result<O> r = transform(item);
          if (r.success) yield return r.value;
       }
       catch {}
    }
}

ReadLines().Reduce(l => { var i; new Tuple<bool, int>(int.TryParse(l.Substring(3,3),i), i)} );
```

I don't really like this, though, as I'm already [on the record as not liking using tuples in this way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72682/is-there-a-name-for-this-anti-pattern-code-smell).  Unfortunately, I don't see many alternatives outside of abusing exceptions or restricting it to reference types (where `null` is defined as a failed conversion), neither of which is much better.

Comment: I looked at this approach.  I just didn't like the fact that the compiler can't infer the type (at least in C# 3), so the "Reduce" extension usability suffers...

Comment: My main complaints are **1)** that I can't express the conversion in a single statement.  I still need a variable declaration inside the lambda.  and **2)** that I have to express the result in form a tuple rather than the converted item.

Answer (score 9):

How about:

```
int? TryParse(string s)
{
    int i;
    return int.TryParse(s, out i) ? (int?)i : (int?)null;
}
IEnumerable<int> XValuesFromFile(string filename)
{
    return from line in ReadLines(filename)
           let start = line.Substring(3,3)
           let parsed = TryParse(start)
           where parsed != null
           select parsed.GetValueOrDefault();
}
```

You could probably combine the second/third lines if you like:

```
    return from line in ReadLines(filename)
           let parsed = TryParse(line.Substring(3,3))
```

The choice of `GetValueOrDefault` is because this skips the validation check that casting `(int)` or `.Value` perform - i.e. it is (ever-so-slightly) faster (and we've already checked that it isn't `null`).

Comment: I guess I'm looking more for the generic case of filtering an enumerable based on a complex transformation - keep the changed version of everything that passed the change.  This may be case for writing a new "operator".

Comment: Is using `!= null` and `GetValueOrDefault()` really faster than using `where parsed.HasValue` and `select parsed.Value`? I guess I should go run some tests, because that seems counter-intuitive to me.

Comment: Another approach is to write a method that returns a `Tuple<bool, T>` result, if you've got .NET 4 or want to write your own Tuple class. This is how F# automatically handles TryParse and similar methods. Then the LINQ would be `where tuple.Item1 select tuple.Item2`

Comment: Joel Mueller: yeah, I was already working on something kinda like that :)

Comment: @Joel Mueller - `!=null` is **exactly** `HasValue`, so that is no different. The `GetValueOrDefault()` is a *tiny* bit faster by skipping the check - it simply returns the inner field directly.

Answer (score 3):

It's not exactly pretty, but you can do:

```
return ReadLines(filename)
    .Select(l =>
                {
                    string tmp = l.Substring(3, 3);
                    int result;
                    bool success = int.TryParse(tmp, out result);
                    return new
                               {
                                   Success = success,
                                   Value = result
                               };
                })
    .Where(i => i.Success)
    .Select(i => i.Value);
```

Granted, this is mostly just pushing the work into the lambda, but it does provide the correct answers, with a single parse (but extra memory allocations).

Comment: Marc's option of using a Nullable<int> could be used here instead of the anonymous class, as well, which would prevent the GC pressure from occurring...