# Select a specific range of elements?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, linq, xpath

I want to select a specific range of elements within my XML files

Here is an example of the XML:

```
<urlset>
    <url>
        <loc>e1</loc>
        <priority>1</priority>
    </url>
    <url>
        <loc>e2</loc>
        <priority>2</priority>
    </url>
    <url>
        <loc>e3</loc>
        <priority>1</priority>
    </url>
    <url>
        <loc>e4</loc>
        <priority>3</priority>
    </url>
    <url>
        <loc>e4</loc>
        <priority>1</priority>
    </url>
    <url>
        <loc>e5</loc>
        <priority>2</priority>
    </url>
</urlset>
```

How to get the value of `e2` to `e4`?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: By value, do you mean the priority?

Comment: Lookup XPath and conditions in []-brackets ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);

var result = doc.Element("urlset").Elements("url")
    .SkipWhile(x => x.Element("loc").Value != "e2")
    .TakeWhile(x => x.Element("loc").Value != "e4");
```

Comment: Wouldn't it just return all the `e2`s and nothing else? I did not downvote by the way, I just undid my upvote (which was for the use of `SkipWhile` and `TakeWhile` - I didn't know these). The OP wants a a range of elements e2 from to e4 (presumably including e3, for example)

Comment: @Morawski, It will return `e2`, `e3` in provided sample, in other words from `e2` to `e4`

Comment: I'd consider using OrderBy, same for Morawski's answer. Although in sample elements are ordered, it may not be the case (that should be cleared by OP). Edit: TakeWhile won't take last element (e4), just checked. Also, you should Select to get the interested value instead of XElement.

Answer (score 2):

```
var result = urlset.Elements("url").Where(url =>
            url.Element("loc").Value.ToString().CompareTo("e2") >= 0 &&
            url.Element("loc").Value.ToString().CompareTo("e4") <= 0).Select(element => element.Element("loc").Value.ToString());
```

It uses standard (string) comparison - same as in alphabetical sorting, and it doesn't protect you against cases where some element would not have `loc` subelement at all (null reference exception would be thrown).

Comment: I should have used `CompareTo` (>= does not work for strings) - I updated this. As for your comment: I just tested it and it works as expected, whether the xml elements are sorted or not. The example given above is inclusive of "e4", if that's not intended just use `("e4") < 0` instead of `<=`. It's admittedly less clean than `SkipWhile` / `TakeWhile`, though.

Comment: Chop off `Select` if you want to retrieve entire XML elements rather than just the `loc` values by themselves.

Comment: Change `e3` to `e10`. It won't select `e10`. As I understand, OP needs elements between `e2` and `e4`.

Comment: Do we want it to select `e10`? `e10` is not between `e2` and `e4`. A problem would occur if you had `e30` (treated as string, it does fall between `e2` and `e4`). But this problem occurs whether you use `Where` or `SkipWhile` / `TakeWhile`, no difference here. A small method converting `"e30"` to `(int)30`, `"e4"` to `(int)4` etc. would be needed.

Comment: Maybe I misinterpret OP question. As I understand, for example, in sequence `1, 2, 10, 3, 4, 5` OP needs elements between `2` and `4`. In this sample: `2, 10, 3`.

Comment: Ah OK I see your point now. I understood it differently. He should probably just clarify this.

Answer (score 1):

an alternative way:

```
var urls = from url in doc.Descendants("urlset").Elements("url")
    let str = Int32.Parse(url.Element("loc").Value.Replace("e",""))
    where str >= 2 && str <= 4  
    select url;
```

or actually, a safer option that doesn't throw exceptions if loc is not in the form "e + integer value" ([courtesy of Marc Gravell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2187037/c-linq-lambda-expression-how-to-select-an-integer-out-of-a-string/2187075#2187075)) would be:

```
int? TryParse(string s)
{
    int i;
    return int.TryParse(s, out i) ? (int?)i : (int?)null;
}

var urls = from url in doc.Descendants("urlset").Elements("url")
    let str = TryParse(url.Element("loc").Value.Replace("e",""))
    where str >= 2 && str <= 4  
    select url;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this XPath:

```
//url[loc = 'e2' or 
    (preceding-sibling::url/loc = 'e2' and following-sibling::url/loc = 'e4')
]
```

It will select `url` with `loc` = `e2`, `e3`, `e4`